# Properly delete data forever and free up the space it was using?

Tags: sql-server-2014, disk-space

I've been having issues finding a real answer to this question as the response is always "Don't do this, it's a bad idea, that space was obviously needed and it will just get used up again in quick order." But that response doesn't apply to me - I have a copy of the production database that I am using solely for developmental purposes - my read/write activites to be limited to a small amount of the database, but I will need to constantly restore the database to overwrite my changes, so I want to reduce the size of the database - I can achieve this by deleting the data in a handful of tables.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Made sure database was in simple recovery mode
2. Ran `DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME` queries
3. Tasks > Shrink > Files > File Type: Log, Release Unused Space - this step was successful and reduced the .ldf to its initial minimum size.
4. Tasks > Shrink > Files > File Type: Data, Release Unused Space - this step did not do anything. It "executed" in half a millisecond and the .mdf is just as big as it was before running the `DELETE` queries...

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is worthless because delete operations are completely logged.
Use truncate instead if you want to empty a table.

About the task 4 you have to reorganize pages because the release pages free only pages ad the end of the mdf file. It will takes a lot.

I suggest you add task 5: rebuild the indexes because shrinking the data file causes the indexes to fragment.